# How to convert HTML to XHTML?

Tags: c#, .net, html, xhtml, converters

I need to convert HTML documents into valid XML, preferably XHTML. What's the best way to do this? Does anybody know a toolkit/library/sample/...whatever that helps me to get that task done?

To be a bit more clear here, my application has to do the conversion automatically at runtime. I don't look for a tool that helps me to move some pages to XHTML manually.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[**Convert from HTML to XML with HTML Tidy**](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/tiptidy.html)

[**Downloadable Binaries**](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/#binaries)

JRoppert, For your need, i guess you might want to look at the [Sources](http://sourceforge.net/cvs/?group_id=27659)

```
c:\temp>tidy -help
tidy [option...] [file...] [option...] [file...]
Utility to clean up and pretty print HTML/XHTML/XML
see http://tidy.sourceforge.net/

Options for HTML Tidy for Windows released on 14 February 2006:

File manipulation
-----------------
 -output <file>, -o  write output to the specified <file>
 <file>
 -config <file>      set configuration options from the specified <file>
 -file <file>, -f    write errors to the specified <file>
 <file>
 -modify, -m         modify the original input files

Processing directives
---------------------
 -indent, -i         indent element content
 -wrap <column>, -w  wrap text at the specified <column>. 0 is assumed if
 <column>            <column> is missing. When this option is omitted, the
                     default of the configuration option "wrap" applies.
 -upper, -u          force tags to upper case
 -clean, -c          replace FONT, NOBR and CENTER tags by CSS
 -bare, -b           strip out smart quotes and em dashes, etc.
 -numeric, -n        output numeric rather than named entities
 -errors, -e         only show errors
 -quiet, -q          suppress nonessential output
 -omit               omit optional end tags
 -xml                specify the input is well formed XML
 -asxml, -asxhtml    convert HTML to well formed XHTML
 -ashtml             force XHTML to well formed HTML
 -access <level>     do additional accessibility checks (<level> = 0, 1, 2, 3).
                     0 is assumed if <level> is missing.

Character encodings
-------------------
 -raw                output values above 127 without conversion to entities
 -ascii              use ISO-8859-1 for input, US-ASCII for output
 -latin0             use ISO-8859-15 for input, US-ASCII for output
 -latin1             use ISO-8859-1 for both input and output
 -iso2022            use ISO-2022 for both input and output
 -utf8               use UTF-8 for both input and output
 -mac                use MacRoman for input, US-ASCII for output
 -win1252            use Windows-1252 for input, US-ASCII for output
 -ibm858             use IBM-858 (CP850+Euro) for input, US-ASCII for output
 -utf16le            use UTF-16LE for both input and output
 -utf16be            use UTF-16BE for both input and output
 -utf16              use UTF-16 for both input and output
 -big5               use Big5 for both input and output
 -shiftjis           use Shift_JIS for both input and output
 -language <lang>    set the two-letter language code <lang> (for future use)

Miscellaneous
-------------
 -version, -v        show the version of Tidy
 -help, -h, -?       list the command line options
 -xml-help           list the command line options in XML format
 -help-config        list all configuration options
 -xml-config         list all configuration options in XML format
 -show-config        list the current configuration settings

Use --blah blarg for any configuration option "blah" with argument "blarg"

Input/Output default to stdin/stdout respectively
Single letter options apart from -f may be combined
as in:  tidy -f errs.txt -imu foo.html
For further info on HTML see http://www.w3.org/MarkUp
```

Comment: Unfortunately first link is dead now. But it seems content still can be found here: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-tiptidy/index.html

Comment: To actually use tidy to create xhtml, as is sought after, it looks like you must pass the `-asxml` flag, otherwise you get non-validating output.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack). Its open-source project from CodePlex.

Answer (score 4):

The [Validator.nu HTML Parser](http://about.validator.nu/htmlparser/) comes with an HTML2XML sample program that does the conversion using the HTML5 parsing algorithm and infoset coercion rules.

Answer (score 4):

Use Html2Xhtml for .NET 4.0:

In-memory string-to-string conversion:

```
var xhtml = Html2Xhtml.RunAsFilter(stdin => stdin.Write(html)).ReadToEnd();
```

In-memory string-to-XDocument conversion:

```
var xdoc = Html2Xhtml.RunAsFilter(stdin => stdin.Write(html)).ReadToXDocument();
```

See http://corsis.sourceforge.net/index.php/Html2Xhtml for more information.

Comment: I had the exact same question and used this answer, it works beautifully.  Especially for the conversion to the XElement.

Comment: How to use it in .netcore 3.1

Comment: @amirkian – see, http://corsis.sourceforge.net/index.php/Html2Xhtml

Comment: @CetinSert It doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 2):

http://corsis.sourceforge.net/index.php/Html2Xhtmlhttp://corsis.sourceforge.net/index.php/Html2Xhtml

Html2Xhtml is a .NET 4.0 library for converting HTML to XHTML licensed under GPLv2 or above.

I tested Html2Xhtml in the local reconstruction of a large online database of the European Union. Tidy/Tidy.NET would not even produce valid output most of the time, Chilkat's HTML-to-XML was a bit slow and produced strange results (misplaced, missing, unexplainable elements). In attempt to find a free, fast and reliable conversion tool I created this library. It converts 2 - 4x faster than all other libraries I tested.

Html2Xhtml, combined with the power of LINQ to XML, is an excellent tool for all large-scale data extraction and web crawling scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

you can convert html to xhtml with tidy executable file:

tidy -asxhtml -numeric < index.html > index.xhml

you can check the c# implementation [here](http://www.dotnetobject.com/Thread-Html-to-Xhtml-conversion-in-c).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to set your Visual Studio IDE to identify the changes you need to make.
You can do this in Visual Studio 2008 by going to:
Tools, Options, Text Editor, HTML, Validation and choosing the appropriate target.
Possibly XHTML 1.1 or XHTML 1.0 Transitional.

For some information on the different types, read:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479043.aspx

Then you need to work through the points highlighted on your page.

Comment: Sorry, i was not clear in my question. I need to do the conversion automatically at runtime.