# extracting only elements with text (or value)

Tags: c#, html, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

hay all.
i am trying to transform html to xml
meaning extracting all elements with text
using this code is not working maybe some one has the answer ?

```
System.Xml.Linq.XElement query1 = new System.Xml.Linq.XElement("RawHTMLData",
           from q in hDoc.Descendants("TABLE")
           where q.HasElements 
           select new System.Xml.Linq.XElement("TABLE" + (++i).ToString(),
           from j in q.Elements("TR")
           where j.HasElements && j.Descendants("div") != null
           select new System.Xml.Linq.XElement("Row",
           from hh in j.Descendants("div")
           where tt => j.Descendants("div").Contains(hh.Value) 
           select(TT(hh)))));
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Linq to Xml to parse HTML becase html may be not valid as xml.

Comment: yes i know ..  this problem is already solved by replacing the bad strings. so no i can
but i want to chose only the XText element \or only the element with value

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would work for you but you might look at using a third party tool such as [HTML Tidy](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-tiptidy.html) to convert from HTML to XHTML.  Then you can treat your html like XML.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138555/how-to-convert-html-to-xhtml) is a link to a post discussing that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net), it has helped me much! :)

Old project Page: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/