# HTML parsing using pugixml or an actual HTML parser

Tags: c++, html, html-parsing, pugixml

I'm interested in using [pugixml](http://pugixml.org/) to parse HTML documents, but HTML has some [optional closing tags](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/index/elements.html). Here is an example: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">`

Pugixml stops reading the HTML as soon as it encounters a tag that's not closed, but in HTML missing a closing tag does not necessarily mean that there is a start-end tag mismatch.

A simple test of parsing the HTML documentation of pugixml fails because the meta tag is the second line of the HTML document: http://pugixml.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/docs/quickstart.html

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
<title>pugixml 1.0</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="pugixml.css" type="text/css">
<meta name="generator" content="DocBook XSL Stylesheets V1.75.2">
<link rel="home" href="quickstart.html" title="pugixml 1.0">
</head>
<!--- etc... -->
```

A lot of HTML documents in the wild would fail if I try to parse them with pugixml. Is there a way to avoid that? If there is no way to "fix" that, then is there another HTML parsing tool that's as about as fast as pugixml?

### Update

It would also be great if the HTML parser also supports XPATH.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up taking pugixml, converting it into an HTML parser and I created a github project for it: https://github.com/rofldev/pugihtml

For now it's not fully compliant with the HTML specifications, but it does a decent enough job at parsing HTML that I can use it. I'm working on making it compliant with the HTML specifications.

Answer (score 1):

One way to address this is to do some pre-processing that converts the HTML to XHTML, then it would "officially" be considered XML and usable with XML tools.  If you want to go that route, see this question:  [How to convert HTML to XHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138555/how-to-convert-html-to-xhtml)